# How to implement RecyclerView GridLayoutManager spanCount change animation coordinated with zoom gesture finger movements in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am eager to know how such a good animation like in stock Samsung Gallery app may be implemented. Changing the span count, the items just perfectly move connected to finger movement flow in zoom gesture.[image: samsung gallery app]